# Connection issues. How to solve them?

Tags: node

I cant connect to the 2.5.4 wallet. I tried different nodes. I even used the top nodes on [Iota.dance/nodes](http://iota.dance/nodes). I even checked the console.
These are the outputs:

[image: No Connection]

[image: Console]

How can I fix it?

Comment: I tried a lot. This is what I said in my second sentance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not own this server, there is nothing you can do other then contact the server owner, then choose a different node to connect to.

A `CONNECTION_REFUSED` error means that the packet was properly forward to a host, but there was not a process bound to the port on the other end ready to accept that packet.

If this is your server, simply put, IRI is not running.

If this is the *same* error presenting across every node you try, you should check your local firewall.